# Efficient use of If Then scenarios in Dask when creating a new column

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements, vectorization, dask

I have a csv with about 11m rows that I'm reading into a dask dataframe. I am attempting to create a new column that is the result of an if/then/else scenario. I'm having some trouble understanding how to get it to work, and just as importantly hot to get it to work efficiently. I'm new to pandas/dask.

Basically this is what I've tried: **Calling a function from the create column event.** This is a simplified example of what I've been trying.

```
#var1 = 0
#var2 = 10

def find_situation:
    If (var1 == 0 and var2 > 10):
        print("Situation 1")
    elif var1 == 0 and var2 < 10:
        print("Situation 2")
    else:
        print("No Situation")

ddf['situation'] = ddf.apply(find_situation(ddf['ddfvar1'], ddf['ddfvar2']))
```

This approach results in an error message stating **"ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()."** The help topics on these actions read like any or all values from the row of data being parsed will be considered, rather than the values I'm passing to the function?

Also, I read that vectorising is far faster, but I'm not sure if this is the sort of scenario where the query can be **vectorised**?

The long version, where I'm just simply trying to determine the value in the month column as a starting point. Really I need to go toward the type of compound if statements I'd made in the simplified example.:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
import dask.multiprocessing
import dask.threaded
import pandas as pd

# Dataframes implement the Pandas API
import dask.dataframe as dd

def f(x):
    if x == 9:
        y = 'Nine'
    elif x == 2:
        y= 'Two'
    else :
        y= 1 
    return y


ddf['AndHSR'] = ddf.apply(f(ddf['Month']))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `np.select` for vectorised approach.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(500)

df = pd.DataFrame({"var1":np.random.randint(0,20,10000000),
                   "var2":np.random.randint(0,25,10000000)})

df["result"] = np.select([(df["var1"]==0)&(df["var2"]>10),
                          (df["var1"]==0)&(df["var2"]<10)],  #list of conditions
                         ["Situation 1", "Situation 2"],     #list of results
                         default="No situation")             #default if no match

print (df.groupby("result").count())

#
                     var1     var2
result                        
No situation  9520776  9520776
Situation 1    279471   279471
Situation 2    199753   199753
```

Comment: Thanks @Henry-Yik. Will this work with a dask dataframe? I'm assuming it will.

Comment: Haven't used dask df before but looking at the docs it is just composed of smaller pandas df so it should probably work.

Comment: Righto. I'll give it a go and get back to you on that. I'll mark as correct too if it works. Dask is generally pd compatible, though not always.

Comment: I can't seem to get code blocks working in comments with a single backtick, triple backtick, or triple tilde. Sigh.

Here's a GIST. 

https://gist.github.com/anakaine/b6eaa22de9fe4180b415246b38f480af

Comment: I am receiving an error with the default value. `default=0` returns `ValueError: invalid entry 0 in condlist: should be boolean ndarray`

Comment: You passed a df instead of a Boolean array in your condition list. Try `ddf[“Month”].between(8,12)` instead. Same for the other condition.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I got that part working. Next error is `TypeError: Column assignment doesn't support type numpy.ndarray`

Dask is a little different from numpy despite apparently being compatilble, unfortunately.

Comment: Gist of the new error:https://gist.github.com/anakaine/b661dd846980dbcf859e427ab445b235